# Dell PowerEdge 16000SC

Tags: placeholder

This is a really really sad question. I have a Dell PowerEdge 16000SC, and I am wondering what it could be used for. I believe it is a server, but if anyone knows specific information on the Dell PowerEdge 16000SC itself, it would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Not a Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a server targetted for small to med size business needs with dual Xeon processors.

Overview from Dell - [Dell.com](http://www.dell.com/downloads/emea/products/pedge/1600sc.pdf)

Here are the specs:

> FEATURES DESCRIPTION
>
> Processors Dual Intel® Xeon™ FC-PGA at 1.8GHz, 2GHz, 2.4GHz or 2.8GHz
>
> Cache 512K L2 cache
>
> Chipset ServerWorks® GC-SL chipset
>
> Front side bus 400MHz
>
> I/O channels Six total: 2 x PCI-X slots (2 x 64-bit/100MHz); 4
> x PCI slots (2 x 64-bit/66MHz; 2 x 32-bit/33MHz)
>
> Network interface card 10/100/1000 embedded NIC
>
> Availability Hot-plug, redundant power(optional); hot-plug hard drives (optional); ECC memory; easy-access chassis
>
> Maximum memory 4GB ECC DDR RAM
>
> Internal storage scalability Up to six hot-plug (or four non-hot-plug) SCSI drives, or up to four IDE drives
>
> Up to 438GB SCSI internal storage Internal storage performance 10,000 and 15,000 rpm U320 SCSI drives or IDE drives
>
> External hard drive storage None
>
> Embedded SCSI (HDDs) Single channel U320
>
> Embedded IDE (HDDs) ATA100 RAID support PERC3/SC single channel U160
>
> RAID controller (SCSI drives) CERC quad-channel ATA RAID (IDE drives)
>
> Tape support Internal: PV 100T TR40, PV 100T DDS4, PV 110T DLT VS80
>
> Video Embedded ATI Rage XL (8MB)
>
> USB performance 1.X
>
> Networking Embedded Intel Gigabit NIC Optional add-in: Intel PRO/100 S NIC, Intel PRO/1000
> XT NIC, Broadcom® 5703 (10/100/1000) NIC, Broadcom ModemXtreme 56KB
>
> V.92 PCI soft modem High availability clustering Not supported
>
> Chassis Easy-access tower (not rackable)
>
> Power supply 1 x 450W or optional 2 x 450W hot-plug redundant
>
> Systems management Integrated server monitoring (ADM1026); OpenManage™ support Remote management
>
> Optional
>
> Dell Remote Assistant Card (DRACIII/XT) Dimensions (H xW x D) 17.61" x
> 8.57" x 22.53" (44.73cm x 21.77cm x 57.23cm) Weight 33.1kg approx. / 73 lbs. maximum configuration